# How to get AWS Location URL in web

Tags: typescript, angular6

how to get URL Location 
I'm not able to do can anybody help

using angular 6
how to get the Entire location in my browser 
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebsgt.png)

I have written this code uploadFile(file) {

```
const contentType = file.type;
const bucket = new S3(
  {
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    region: 'us-east-2'
  }
);
const params = {
  Bucket: 'test123re',
  Key: 'test123re/' + file.name,
  Body: file,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  ContentType: 'application/json'
};
bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
    return false;
  }
  console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
  this.resssss = data;
  console.log('Successfully.', this.resssss);
  this.location = this.resssss.Location;
  console.log('AwsLocation.', this.location);

});
```

}
component.ts file I'm getting result console, 
I need not in the browser

## AWS URL get here {{AwsLocation}}

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get the Entire location in my browser"? Do you want to display it on the page?

Comment: yes we need display page

Comment: Add your file upload page code.

Comment: <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!selectedFiles" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>

Comment: Take another empty div element `<div id='showurl'></div>` 
Add this before the line `console.log('AwsLocation', ...)` 
`document.getElementById('showurl').innerHTML =  this.location`

Comment: If it's helped you then kindly upvote the comment. Thanks

Comment: how to get outside Location in console

Comment: bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
    return false;
  }
  console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
  this.resssss = data;
  console.log('Successfully.', this.resssss);
  this.location = this.resssss.Location;
  console.log('AwsLocation.', this.location);

}); 
//how to get URL Location outside bucket upload we need ouside Location value

 console.log('Location outside access', this.location);